# SVN Access Restricted to Creator

Tags: svn, permissions, svn-checkout, svnserve

I am new to SVN and I'm trying to create a repository for a group project. I have been able to create, checkout, import and generally work with the repository. However, when my colleagues attempt to access the repository with the same command, the following errors appear.

```
$ svn checkout file:///tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/
svn: Unable to open ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/'
svn: Berkeley DB error for filesystem '/tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/db' while opening environment:

svn: Permission denied.
```

For good measure, I set the svnserve.conf file to

```
[general]
anon-access = write
auth-access = write
```

I think that my problem currently lies in the "file:///" URL, and that maybe I should use svnserve to use a "svn://" URL. However, I tried this with no avail, yielding a different error.

```
$ svn checkout svn://$USER@`hostname`/tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/
svn: Can't connect to host 'ca02-ws0000': connection refused
```

I am at a loss now. Hence, my presence here. Thank you for any insight you can give me.

Edit: Okay, so after running svnserve as daemon and using the svn:// URL, my colleague received the following trying to open my repository.

```
$ svn checkout svn://$USER@`hostname`/tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos
svn: Berkeley DB error while opening environment for filesystem /tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/db: Permission denied.
```

After seeing that error, I thought permissions the issue and did

```
chmod 777 /db/*
```

And my colleague tried again and received a slightly different error plus a bonus error!

```
$ svn checkout svn://$USER@`hostname`/tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos
svn: Berkeley DB error while opening environment for filesystem /tmp_mnt/home/malavin/workbench/repos/db: Invalid argument.
svn: bdb: Program version 4.2 doesn't match environment version.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "file://" is a URL for local repository access method. You have to look first at the OS file system permissions.

To use the "svn://" method the svnserve daemon must be running, and it seems that it isn't running.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So "file://" URLs cannot be accessed by another user? I have completely opened (chmod 777) the repository and all of the files in it.

Comment: If you have completely opened the path, that is a problem.

Comment: A problem how? Can you explain your meaning?

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that you have share the repo folder to others (read permission is OK).

2.Check the listen port of your svn server.and grant your svn path like svn://hotsname:PortNo./project